# system("echo text > t.log") reports error

Tags: c, linux, shell

The following code is intend to get and set `RLIMIT_NOFILE`, then do `exec` and `system`:

```
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void show_nofile()
{
    struct rlimit rl;
    if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rl)) {
        perror("getrlimit");
    }
    printf("rlim_cur = %ld, rlim_max =%ld\n", rl.rlim_cur, rl.rlim_max);
}

int set_nofile(long cur, long max)
{
    struct rlimit rl;
    rl.rlim_cur = cur;
    rl.rlim_max = max;
    if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &rl)) {
        perror("setrlimit");
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    show_nofile();
    if (argc<2) {
        set_nofile(9, 10);
        show_nofile();
        printf("now execlp...\n");
        execlp("./a.out", "a.out", "-n", (char*)NULL);
    } else {
        if (-1==system("/bin/echo abc > log")) {
            perror("system");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is how i compile and run it `gcc -Wall limit.c && ./a.out`, the result is:

```
rlim_cur = 1024, rlim_max =4096
rlim_cur = 9, rlim_max =10
now execlp...
rlim_cur = 9, rlim_max =10
sh: 1: 1: Invalid argument
```

What could be wrong here?

P.S.:
I run it in my home dir, so there is not permission problems.
Besides, the error message does not seem to relate file permission.

Comment: Could you post the full program so we can try to reproduce it?   http://www.sscce.org/  How are you compiling it and running it?

Comment: this system() call is correct. error is in some other part of code mostly. so post rest of the code

Comment: @adamsmith the code is right. and it works fine if you change command inside system(). but system("/bin/echo abc > log") is also right format that runs. so i think here some thing related processes concepts is involved.

Comment: Wow, how come there was no mention of setrlimit in the original question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set a too low limit for `RLIMIT_NOFILE`.

`strace` your program, you will find lines like

```
10512 open("def", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
10512 fcntl(1, F_DUPFD, 10)             = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
10512 close(1)                          = 0
```

which means `sh` cannot redirect I/O successfully.

Please replace

```
set_nofile(9, 10);
```

with

```
set_nofile(12, 20);
```

and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Is the "text" a variable? If so, you may need to try this:

```
system("echo $text > t.log");
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be nothing wrong with the code as such..
Try to check the write permissions on the directory you are trying to execute the program in.
On successful execution, your file "t.log" will only contain the word "text".

@Yunxuan Tuanmu: '$text' will be the shell's context, which will be null since it is not set within that context